# Isolating specific data out of a larger data set with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to isolate only Seattle MSA employment data since 2000 out of the BLS data set of every single MSA in the country since 1990. There are approximately 200,000 rows in this data set and all I need are about 70 of them. I have managed to successfully delete all the unnecessary data with a run time of 50s (not great but fine for what I am doing).
My problem is that I need the code to be relative, meaning each month when I want to update it, my code needs to accommodate one more row of data per MSA. The way I had approached getting the data was by chunking. First I got rid of all the data before 2000, easy this will always have the same number of rows. Then I sorted the data by state. Washington is close to the end of the filtered list, but still in the middle. This means I have two chunks:

1. Row 1 to the row where Washington starts (right now that is row 71,556)
2. Then where Washington ends to the end of data

How can I most efficiently and accurately count up to Washington? I am open to restructuring my data entirely, I just have no idea how to in VBA (I am new).

```
Sub FillDataBLS()

'
' FillDataBLS Macro
' Fills data from BLS that has been save as Data.csv in the BLS Data folder.
'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;Z:\Seattle Office Market Analysis\BLS Data\Data.csv",     Destination:= _
    range("$A$1"))
    .Name = "Data"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 437
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With

'Sets font style and size'
With range("A1").CurrentRegion.Font
    .Size = 10
    .FontStyle = "Book Antiqua"
End With

'Removes blank rows above header'
Rows("1:2").EntireRow.Delete
Rows(2).EntireRow.Delete

'Remove years 1990-1999'
firstRow = 2
lastRow = 47281
Rows("2:47281").EntireRow.Delete 'this will always be the same length


'Sort by State FIPS Code and delete all but 53'
range("A1").CurrentRegion.Sort Key1:=range("B2"), Order1:=xlAscending
firstRow = 1
'lastRow
Rows("1:71556").EntireRow.Delete 'find a way to count these rows specifically
'firstRow
'lastRow
Rows("2212:7638").EntireRow.Delete 'find a way to count these rows specifically

'Finds only Seattle MSA data'
k = 2211
j = 1 'for the quarterly'
For i = k To 1 Step -1
   If Cells(i, 1).Value = "MT5342660000000" Then
        Cells(i, 8).Font.Bold = True
    Else
        Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i

'Sets up Column Titles'
range("A1").CurrentRegion.Sort Key1:=range("A1"), Order1:=xlAscending
Rows(1).Font.Bold = True
Rows(1).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlDouble

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a sub I used myself, if I understood what you want correctly you'll find it useful, it deletes all rows from the sheet that do not include the given value of a column:

```
Sub IsolateDataRows(dataHeader As String, sData As String)
  Dim valueColumn As Long, valueRow As Long, count As Long
  Dim tCell As Range
  Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

  ' find data column
  Set tCell = ws.Rows(1).Find(what:=dataHeader, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
  valueColumn = tCell.Column

  ' sort sheet by wanted column
  ws.Columns("A:D").Sort key1:=ws.Columns(valueColumn), _
    Order1:=xlAscending, header:=xlYes, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom

  ' find data's first occurance
  Set tCell = ws.Columns(valueColumn).Find(what:=sData, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
  valueRow = tCell.row

  ' get count of data occurances
  count = Application.CountIf(ws.Columns(valueColumn), sData)

  ' delete rows before and after your data
  ws.Rows(valueRow + count & ":" & ws.Rows.count).EntireRow.Delete
  If valueRow > 2 Then ws.Rows("2:" & valueRow - 1).EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

For example:

```
IsolateDataRows "City", "Washington"
```